# Possiblity to change default language in windows speech recogniton for Tamil

Tags: windows-7, windows

Usually we used to use English language in Windows speech recognition tool to control computer through microphones. now my question is:

Is there any possibility to add more languages to speech recognition tool?

For example consider Tamil language. I need to perform actions based on my Tamil words.

Is there any method/ third party tool to add a language to Windows speech recognizer?

I need it for Tamil language (as Tamil language is used by many people).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer (since original question has changed / been updated)

It depends on what program you are using but this does Tamil

[Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-solution/customer-service-solutions/solutions-services/inbound-solutions/self-service-automation/recognizer/recognizer-languages/index.htm)

Comment: amazing answer thanks i ll try  ,can i get any freeware sir?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Speech Recognition is available only when the language of the operating system matches the language of Windows Speech Recognition.

You can change the language of the operating system by installing a language pack from Windows Update. If you install the language pack of a supported Windows Speech Recognition language, you can then use Windows Speech Recognition for that language if that is also the language of the operating system.

See this article from Microsoft (I know it says Vista but applies to W7) : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934377

Answer resourced from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/80652-speech-recognition-change-language.html)

Comment: it can be applied up to windows vista versions,its not working with windows 7,i reviewed the article it mentions that it can be done up to vista see the applies to paragraph in the page you mentioned

Comment: It is the same for W7 I am afraid.

Comment: @ sir i already tried in windows7 but it doesn't works,i installed additional packages by following this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813

Comment: Windows Speech Recognition supports the following languages:    US English,     UK English,     French,     Spanish,     German,     Japanese,     Traditional Chinese,     Simplified Chinese. Unless I'm really ignorant, Tamil is a South Indian / North-east Sri Lanka language (which if so is not in the list and therefore, as per the article I linked too (in which the languages are listed), will not work).